# AOP how to get log, URL mapping value content on @RequestMapping

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, aop

With AOP how to get log, URL mapping value content on @RequestMapping. 
As a example I want to replace following Logs with AOP @Before advise. Thanks.

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/trail/findMediasForTrail/{trailId}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Media findMediasForTrail(@PathVariable String trailId,
                                                            HttpServletResponse response) {

        logger.info("#############################################################");
        logger.info("#### Skeleton-[/trail/findMediasForTrail/{trailId}] Start ###");
        logger.info("#############################################################");

        logger.info("------ Input Parameters -----");
        logger.info("TrailId [" + trailId + "]");
        logger.info("-----------------------------");
```

Comment: What have you tried?, do you say, this method being intercepted for a "generic logger method"?, and the last one, can you post the related context lines?

Comment: @Diego Jimeno. No I want to log the URL mapping value content with "@RequestMapping".